# facebook invite notification not working in ios

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using the AppInvite in Facebook SDK for iOS.The problem is the end Users/Friends whom the AppInvite is sent to, don't receive the push notifications The Users dont have the App installed.And the Applink url is working fine.

The app is running in production mode, have already added the users as TestUsers also.

Answer (score 0):

From Facebook docs at [App invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/overview)

**If the person already has the app installed, they will not receive a push notification.**

So make sure you uninstall the application from the device which receiving the invitation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response, but i use a fresh user with new device and no luck

Comment: Have they ever installed the app? Also, adding real users in a Test role for your app is not the same as creating Test Users https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Comment: The invite will always show up in the App Invites section. If the user has installed the app previously, they may not get a push notification. The ideal way to test it is to use a new test user (using the link I sent above), who's never installed the app, and send them an invite.